# Generating Adio Fingerprint with GraceNote SDK

Tags: c++, c, gracenote

I am having some trouble understanding the samples included in the gnsdk download. All I need to do is to be able to generate an audio fingerprint from a wav. file. My plan is then to hand it off the the web api to query the database. I am much more experienced in web languages so once I can get the fingerprint I shoudl be good to go. Unfortunately my C/C++ is a bit shaky.

I am trying to figure out the exact function I need to call and how to pass a wave file to it. If anybody has any tips or clues on how to just generate the finger print I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the sample source code under 'samples/musicid_lookup_album_fpx'.
In the main.c file look for the following functions.

APIs for generating finger prints from PCM.

- gnsdk_musicid_query_fingerprint_begin()
- gnsdk_musicid_query_fingerprint_write()
- gnsdk_musicid_query_fingerprint_end()

API for saving finger print to a string buffer.

- gnsdk_musicid_query_get_fp_data()